# Why does std::initializer_list not support std::get<>, std::tuple_size and std::tuple_element

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, initializer-list, structured-bindings

Why does `std::initializer_list` not support `std::get<>`, `std::tuple_size` and `std::tuple_element`?  It is used a lot in `constexpr` expressions as is right now, for example,

```
std::max({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
```

And if it did cool things like the following would be possible

```
auto [x, y] = {1, 2};
```

So why does `std::initializer_list` not support these?  As far as I know there is no way to construct a `std::initializer_list` at runtime, so the size is always fixed by the user.

---

Below is an example of how one can get the size of an `std::intializer_list<>` at compile time

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <typename...>  struct WhichType;

template <typename Type>
constexpr int size_init_list(std::initializer_list<Type> il) {
    return il.end() - il.begin();
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto size = size_init_list({1, 2, 3});
    cout << static_cast<int>(std::integral_constant<int, size>{}) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @downvoter why the downvote?

Comment: auto i = randint(0,1) ? std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2} : std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

Comment: Why not just end - begin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though the size of a `std::initializer_list` is a compile-time constant, the size isn't part of the type. Every initializer list of `int`s has the same type, namely `std::initializer_list<int>`. And `std::tuple_size<std::initializer_list<int>>::value` can only have one possible value. So obviously it cannot be used to get the actual size of an initializer list. It makes no sense to define it at all.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: @Curious yes, you can get the size at compile time, but that doesn't mean `std::tuple_size` can do it. In my answer I explained why: it is only given the type, not the instance.

Comment: Stupid question on my part.